# C# WPF animation of checkbox flickers

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

When I click my checkbox a message box shows up with a simple warning that crashes can occur when changing the checkbox to true. I must press yes and the checkbox will be checked and the check animation starts.

But as you can see in the video, the animation starts too when I click the checkbox and the slider jumps back immediately:

[image: Video]

**I want to start the animation when the checkbox is finally checked and avoid this flickering.**
How can I achieve this?

My **checkbox click event**:

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    
    var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

    var messageBoxResult = MyMessageBoy.Show("Crashes can occur when changing the checkbox to true")

    // if yes checkbox should be checked
    if (messageBoxResult == BoxResult.Yes)
    {
       checkbox.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

This is my **control template** and **storyboard**:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedTrue">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="slider">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-0.25" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="33.875" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedFalse">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="34" />
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-0.25" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedFalse}" x:Name="OnUnchecking_BeginStoryboard" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedTrue}" x:Name="OnChecking_BeginStoryboard" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option would be to move your storyboard from the control template to the code behind and only begin your animation in the If branch that checks that your BoxResult is yes.

You can take a look at this [Start Storyboard from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815532/start-storyboard-from-c-sharp-code) for reference.